# weird error "operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'"

Tags: c#

Okay, I have this code:

```
decimal jewels = numericUpDown1.Value;
int price = 0.35 / 100 * jewels;
MessageBox.Show(price.ToString());
```

But for some weird reason I get this error: `

> operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'`.

I've tried using all the different types, like float, double and int and none of them work!

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't multiply a `decimal` and a `double` directly. (`0.35/100` is a `double`). Cast the `double` to a `decimal` first, or vice versa.

Comment: Simplify it by making them both equal type - then concert back to int.  int i = Convert.ToInt32(0.35m * 100m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't multiply a `decimal` value witha `double` value. If you use `decimal` literal values, the multiplication works fine:

```
0.35M / 100M * jewels
```

To assign it to an `int` variable you have to cast the result to `int`:

```
int price = (int)(0.35M / 100M * jewels);
```

You might want to round the `decimal` value first, as just casting it will truncate the value:

```
int price = (int)Math.Round(0.35M / 100M * jewels);
```

Comment: I recommend passing in the MidpointRounding argument on Round.  MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero will most likely round the way you intend.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Trevor: As the value that is rounded is a price, bankers rounding seems more appropriate. That is the default for the `Round` method.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will work,

```
decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(0.35 / 100) * jewels;
```

and if you want price to be int:

```
int price = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDecimal(0.35 / 100) * jewels);
```

And.. I think that jewels does not need to be decimal, since its value is coming from numeric up down control that would be always int?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically convert from decial to other number formats such as double. So try:

```
int price = 0.35 / 100 * Convert.ToDouble(jewels);
```

Or:

```
int price = 0.35 / 100 * (double)jewels;
```